# How to clearCheck all radio groups and setTextColor to only one radio button in Java?

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, onclicklistener

I've created dynamically 2 radio groups with 2 radio buttons. Each radio button represents an answer to a question. I setOnCheckedChangeListener to see which of the anwsers is correct. So, when i press a button, i want to have all radio groups `clearCheck()` and also the correct answer `setTextColor(Color.GREEN)`. With this code, when i use `radioGroup[i].clearCheck();` i get this error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.widget.RadioButton.getTag()' on a null object reference`. How can i fix this? And how can i set text color green, only to the right answers? Here is my code:

```
      radioGroup[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);
                int  CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(checkedRadioButton.getTag().toString());
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case 0:
                        if (CorrectAnswer == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked the correct answer ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            score++;
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked the incorrect answer ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (CorrectAnswer == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked the correct answer ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            score++;
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked the incorrect answer ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
                    radioGroup[i].clearCheck(); // doesn't work
                    for (int j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
                        radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        ((RadioButton) radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j)).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: please show code where adding view in `radioGroup[i]`

Comment: `radioGroup = new RadioGroup[2];
answer = new RadioButton[2];
int i = 0;
for (Question qn : questions) {
    radioGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
    int j = 0;
    for (Answer an : answers) {
        if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
            answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
            answer[j].setText(an.getAnswer());
            answer[j].setId(j);
            answer[j].setTag(String.valueOf(an.getCorrect_answer()));
            radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup[i]);
}`

Comment: To see more clearly: [link](http://gogo.ro/6.png)

Comment: Do you have any idea, how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: you mean not able to clear all selected RadioButtons using clearCheck ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I can't clearCheck() all radio groups.

Comment: try to do it as: `radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j). setChecked(false)`

Comment: I already did this. But it doesn't solve me the problem because if i set the check box again enable, the first radio button that i checked, remains checked. That's way i need to clearCheck() the radio groups, not to setChecked(false) the radio buttons.

Comment: what happen when using `radioGroup[i].clearCheck();` ??

Comment: I get this error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.widget.RadioButton.getTag()' on a null object reference`
You helped me yesterday with something similar. Can you help me also with this? And the second problem is, how can i set text color green, only to the right answers?

Comment: I thinks this is something about what you told me to do yesterday regarding that `int  CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(checkedRadioButton.getTag().toString());`
This is the error log: [link](www.gogo.ro/7.png) Hope this helps.

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: I provided you a few second ago, the error log.

Comment: In `int  CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(checkedRadioButton.getTag().toString());` line?

Comment: I dont't know but what can i say is that before i added this lines, the `radioGroup[i].clearCheck();` was working fine. Is there any connection between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `onCheckedChanged` method is calling when  `clearCheck` method is called so add `null` check in `onCheckedChanged`  before calling `toString()` method on `setTag` method:

```
@Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
      RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);
      if(checkedRadioButton!=null)
      if(checkedRadioButton.getTag() !=null){
        int  CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(
                         checkedRadioButton.getTag().toString());
          ....your code here

       } 
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i do that?

Comment: Isn't working. Seems now that the `onCheckedChanged` doesn't work. The error is: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioGroup cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton`.

Comment: Please, take a look: [link](http://www.gogo.ro/8.png) and this is the error: [link](http://www.gogo.ro/9.png)

Comment: @AlexM.: i think `onCheckedChanged ` method code is ok now problem is occurring due to `radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        ((RadioButton) radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j)).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);` lines please check it after commenting it

Comment: I did this: [link](http://gogo.ro/10.png) and the result is this: [link](http://gogo.ro/11.png) Same error as before, when all this lines were ok.

Comment: Now it's happening something strange. Even those lines are commented or not, it's working but only for one click. After i check the second radio button, it's crushes again. What is to? This is the error: [link](http://gogo.ro/12.png)

Comment: Take a look at the entire file: [link](http://gogo.ro/MainActivity.txt) Maybe it's helps.

Comment: Do you have any new ideas regarding this code? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexM.: share crash log which is occurring using new  code

Comment: For the moment i have 5 radio groups. When i check a radio button for the first time, from radio group 1,2,3,4 and after this i check another one, even if is from the same radio group or another radio group, it crushes. The error is: [link](http://gogo.ro/13.png). When i check a radio button, from the last radio group, every thing it's fine. I can switch between all 4 radio button and everything goes fine, even if i press the button, doesn't crush. What is wrong with the first 4?
Hope it helps.